# Port shows as closed even though it is forwarded

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, port

I'm trying to forward two ports (1033, 58846) but it's not working so far. When I check through open port checking tools it shows they are closed. I am using BSNL WiMAX.

The port forwarding steps is as below:

[image]

This is the port forwarding page in BSNL WiMAX. Have I configured them correctly? If so, why are they not working?

Answer (score 0):

change 127.0.0.1 to your PC's IP LAN address

Comment: Now the port is open. But cannot access the port using external IP.

Comment: make sure modem gateway port is also forwarded also in browser to router WAN IP or PC IP.  Often Cable Modems have NAT also.